# Migrating away from Rackspace (slicehost) to Amazon

Tags: cloud, rackspace, outage

After yet another [Rackspace outage](http://status.rackspacecloud.com/cloudservers/) (ongoing as I type this, no ETA) I'm forced to look at options.

Rackspace has simply not delivered the uptime that my customers expect and I'll admit that I'm disappointed:  I read so many good things about them that just haven't been true in my experience.

Q1: 
Is there an **easy** way to migrate servers from Rackspace to Amazon?

Q2:
Are there any other platforms people here can recommend?  I know that Rackspace is popular, but it simply does not have the stability I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had to migrate a site from Rackspace Slices to EC2 some time ago.

Unfortunately the images are incompatible between EC2 and Rackspace Slices, so the only way is to configure your site again in parallel at EC2 and switch the DNS once you've gone through all the testing and you're sure everything is okay.

All being said, I'm quite satisfied with the change myself :)

Comment: Were you having trouble with their platform, too, or did you migrate away from Rackspace for another reason?

Comment: I had some escalation problems, uptime issues as well and also difficulty to get through first level support to people that could actually help me